# Pubsubhubbub handle in php

Tags: php, feed, publish-subscribe

I need to watch a certain feed for my web app and i can't find any proper documentation about this topic

-Edited:

what i'm actually after is probably so simple that it might be embarrassing :)
i know the hub will use a POST request to deliver the updates but i don't know how to fetch that data using $_POST because i don't know the key value in the $_POST array

I'd love to see basic PHP code example on how this is done

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK

problem solved, i found the protocol wrappers section at php.net.

"php://input" is what i was looking for

http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how good it is, but there is an implementation being developped in Zend Framework ; it's currently still in incubator, but maybe it might interest you : [`/standard/incubator/library/Zend/Feed/Pubsubhubbub`](http://framework.zend.com/code/browse/Zend_Framework/standard/incubator/library/Zend/Feed/Pubsubhubbub)